# How to explain the two way of Clang code generation for short-circuit evaluations?

Tags: clang, llvm

Original C code is

```
struct Customer
{CityName city;     // city name
 FavcName favorite; // favorite category of goods
 int   age;         // age 
 int   gender;      // 1 = M; 2 = F; 3 = genderfluid;
 bool  married;     // true = married
 int   reg;         // registration date (unixtime)
 int   lastdeal;    // last deal date (unixtime)
 float total; };    // total spended (UAH)

bool __cdecl filter_A( har city[24], char favorite[24], int age, int gender, bool married, int reg, int lastdeal, float total)
{ return strcmp(favorite,"Tools") == 0 && age <= 25; }

bool __cdecl filter_B(Customer c)
{ return strcmp(c.favorite,"Tools") == 0 && c.age <= 25; }
```

Use clang with -O1 optimization and get:
(name mangling replased to normal names)

```
define dso_local noundef zeroext i1 @filter_A(ptr %0, ptr %1, i32 %2, i32 %3, i1 %4, i32 %5, i32 %6, float %7) {
  %9 = tail call i32 @strcmp(ptr %1, ptr @"Tools")
  %10 = icmp eq i32 %9, 0
  %11 = icmp slt i32 %2, 26
  %12 = and i1 %11, %10
  ret i1 %12
}

define dso_local noundef zeroext i1 @filter_B(ptr %0) {
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.Customer, ptr %0, i64 0, i32 1
  %3 = tail call i32 @strcmp(ptr %2, ptr @"Tools")
  %4 = icmp eq i32 %3, 0
  br i1 %4, label %5, label %9

5:                                                ; preds = %1
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.Customer, ptr %0, i64 0, i32 2
  %7 = load i32, ptr %6, align 4, !tbaa !4
  %8 = icmp slt i32 %7, 26
  br label %9

9:                                                ; preds = %5, %1
  %10 = phi i1 [ false, %1 ], [ %8, %5 ]
  ret i1 %10
}
```

So why in Filter_A are doesn't used short-circuit evaluation, while Filter_B does?

The logic expression is same in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation why this is happening

To understand why this is the case, you need to look at what benefit you get from short-circuiting and what the added cost is.

For `filter_B` you add the short-circuit branch, but eliminate a load from `c.age` in the case that the first comparison evaluates to `0`.

Now we look at `filter_A`. In this function, there is no need to load `age` from memory, as `age` is located in a virtual register, not a memory location. Since comparing two values produces no side effects, the compiler decides the compare is cheaper than a short-circuit branch.

### Forcing `filter_A` to also short-circuit

If you change the `age` variable to be `volatile`, you force the compiler to assume that loading the variable might have side effects. In this case, the code will be similar to your second case. See [this example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d6aaoqMPq).